# Making loop for data sent by json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I was able to do a data display using the json But how can I print all database in to div or table ??

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'server.php',
    dataType:"json",
    success : function (data) { 

      alert(data[1].name);

    }
  }); 
});
```

php

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
    $statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
    $statement->execute();
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
     echo $json;

?>
```

Comment: you can use a table library ( like datatables )

Comment: with an for of data, and using jquery to generate the new DOM

Answer (score 0):

create a html file with at least one div:

```
<html>
   <div id="test"></div>
</html>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'server.php',
    dataType:"json",
    success : function (data) { 
      for(var y=0; y< data.length; y++){
        $("#test").append(data[y].name + " ");
      }
    }
  }); 
});
```